# Embedding htaccess password dialogue in a webpage (w PHP)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, security

There is a simple way to password protect a website directory using `htacess` and `htpasswd` files. More here: https://css-tricks.com/easily-password-protect-a-website-or-subdirectory/

But when it asks the user for a password it does so using a popup dialogue box at the browser level, see below:

[image]

Is is possible to communicate w the server via PHP so as to embed this interaction (i.e. requesting a username and password that works using the aforementioned technique) directly into a web page? If so, how would one go about this?

Comment: Just build a standard `<form>` and process the input you receive. Store whether or not it worked in a session variable.

Comment: @ceejayoz Does this work w the htaccess technique or are you suggesting a different technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "htaccess technique" uses a feature of the HTTP protocol, which is embedded HTTP authentication. This is a standardised protocol, which browsers implement with a standardised UI. You cannot change that UI. If you want a regular "in-page authentication" with a login form etc, you need to implement it entirely yourself using sessions and a custom HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

That popup is provided by Apache (or installed webserver) to manage authentication on the first level. That allows you to be authenticated in all the webserver.

Authentication in PHP is only (by default) a webpage login.

The Server Authentication is locking, because if you don't have the username you cant do anything.

The PHP Authentication is configurable by you in all senses.

**Both authentications are correct, but they are used for different things.**

Comment: "popup is provided by Apache" is rather... misleading. The popup is produced by the *browser*, Apache has nothing to do with UIs.